# An integer hashing problem

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, hash

I have a (C++) `std::map<int, MyObject*>` that contains a couple of millions of objects of type `MyObject*`. The maximum number of objects that I can have, is around 100 millions. The key is the object's id. During a certain process, these objects must be somehow marked( with a `0` or `1`) as fast as possible. The marking cannot happen on the objects themselves (so I cannot introduce a member variable and use that for the marking process). Since I know the minimum and maximum id (1 to 100_000_000), the first thought that occured to me, was to use a `std::bit_set<100000000>` and perform my marking there. This solves my problem and also makes it easier when marking processes run in parallel, since these use their own bit_set to mark things, but I was wondering what the solution could be, if I had to use something else instead of a `0`-`1` marking, e.g what could I use if I had to mark all objects with an integer number ?

Is there some form of a data structure that can deal with this kind of problem in a compact (memory-wise) manner, and also be fast ? The main queries of interest are whether an object is marked, and with what was marked with.

Thank you.

**Note: `std::map<int, MyObject*>` cannot be changed.** Whatever data structure I use, must not deal with the map itself.

Answer (score 4):

How about making the `value_type` of your map a `std::pair<bool, MyObject*>` instead of `MyObject*`?

Comment: I cannot change that, unfortunately.

Comment: in that case i'd also go with a std::bitset. 100,000,000 bits is only 12.5MB.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not concerned with memory, then a `std::vector<int>` (or whatever suits your need in place of an `int`) should work.

If you don't like that, and you can't modify your map, then why not create a parallel map for the markers?

```
std::map<id,T> my_object_map;
std::map<id,int> my_marker_map;
```

<s>If you cannot modify the objects directly, have you considered wrapping the objects before you place them in the map?  e.g.:</s>

```
struct
{
    int marker;
    T *p_x;
} T_wrapper;


std::map<int,T_wrapper> my_map;
```

If you're going to need to do lookups anyway, then this will be no slower.

**EDIT:** As @tenfour suggests in his/her answer, a `std::pair` may be a cleaner solution here, as it saves the `struct` definition.  Personally, I'm not a big fan of `std::pair`s, because you have to refer to everything as `first` and `second`, rather than by meaningful names.  But that's just me...

Comment: I cannot change my map, and memory is a big concern.

Comment: I did consider of using another, but somehow did not like the whole idea. Maybe I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The most important question to ask yourself is "How many of these 100,000,000 objects might be marked (or remain unmarked)?"  If the answer is smaller than roughly  `100,000,000/(2*sizeof(int))`, then just use another `std::set` or `std::tr1::unordered_set` (`hash_set` previous to `tr1`) to track which ones are so marked (or remained unmarked).

Where does `2*sizeof(int)` come from?  It's an estimate of the amount of memory overhead to maintain a heap structure in a deque of the list of items that will be marked.

If it is larger, then use `std::bitset` as you were about to use.  It's overhead is effectively 0% for the scale of quantity you need.  You'll need about 13 megabytes of contiguous ram to hold the bitset.

If you need to store a marking as well as presence, then use `std::tr1::unordered_map` using the key of `Object*` and value of `marker_type`.   And again, if the percentage of marked nodes is higher than the aforementioned comparison, then you'll want to use some sort of `bitset` to hold the number of bits needed, with suitable adjustments in size, at 12.5 megabytes per bit.

A purpose-built object holding the `bitset` might be your best choice, given the clarification of the requirements.

---

*Edit*: this assumes that you've done proper time-complexity computations for what are acceptable solutions to you, since changing the base `std::map` structure is no longer permitted.

Comment: Good answer, but remember that time complexity (as well as memory complexity) may come into this decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using hacks, take a look at the [memory optimization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#ordered_node_compression) used in Boost.MultiIndex. It can store one bit in the LSB of a stored pointer.

Comment: But the OP's question is about what one does when one wants to store *more* than a single bit per node...